# Why does keyboard.h add 136 to each key?

Tags: keyboard

I want to create a custom keyboard mapping in the [official arduino keyboard library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/)

Why do the key definitions add 136 to each number?

[See Keyboard_es_ES.h on github](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Keyboard/blob/master/src/Keyboard_es_ES.h#L37-L42)

```
#define KEY_MASCULINE_ORDINAL    (136+0x35)
#define KEY_INVERTED_EXCLAMATION (136+0x2e)
#define KEY_GRAVE                (136+0x2f)
#define KEY_N_TILDE              (136+0x33)
#define KEY_ACUTE                (136+0x34)
#define KEY_C_CEDILLA            (136+0x31)
```

Looking at the [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/), I see nothing special about value 136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be argued that this is an implementation detail of the library,
that does not need to be documented. ;-) Anyway, here is the reason...

The keyboard library uses a custom encoding scheme for representing
*both* characters and keys. The public methods `press()`, `release()`,
`write()`, `print()` and `println()` interpret the user-provided data
according to this scheme. With this encoding, the interpretation of a
byte depends on which of these three ranges it belongs to:

- Bytes in the range [0, 127] are understood to be ASCII
  characters. This is what enables you to write things like
  `Keyboard.println("Hello!");`. The library uses a keyboard layout
  array to map those characters to key scan codes¹, possibly modified by
  Shift or AltGr. You provide a pointer to this array as an argument to
  `begin()`.
- Bytes in the range [128, 135] are interpreted as modifier keys,
  such as `KEY_LEFT_CTRL`, `KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT`, etc. Note that these keys
  do not have proper scan codes, as their state is transmitted to the
  host as a bit map (one byte for the eight keys) rather than as codes
  added to a list.
- Bytes in the range [136, 255] are interpreted as raw scan codes
  in the range [0, 119], shifted by 136. This is what lets you
  actuate arbitrary keys such as `KEY_PRINT_SCREEN` or `KEY_LEFT_ARROW`.
  All scan codes of a standard full-size PC keyboard (ANSI 104 or
  ISO 105) lie in the range [4, 101]: you can access all of
  them, and even some more like `KEY_F24`.

Regarding the file Keyboard_es_ES.h: the codes in there are for keys
that match ASCII characters in the US layout but not in the Spanish
layout. The purpose is to ensure that every key of a ISO 105
keyboard can be actuated using either an ASCII character (like
`Keyboard.press('a');`) or a `KEY_*` macro.

¹ The USB standard calls them “usage codes”, but the old term “scan
codes” seems more prevalent.

Comment: Just an idea for self-documenting source, but I'm quite sure you are aware of this. ;-) You could use symbolic constants instead of magic numbers.